# How do I handle slash on web.config rewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I handle product id with slash.

Sample product id: PRODTSP/10

This causes a page error :

```
"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."
```

I also tried putting this escaped string to URL, but still the error occurred: PRODTSP%2F10

This is my current configuration:

```
<rewrite url="^~/Product/id/([^/\\\'=]+)(/?)$" to="~/View/Product.aspx?id=$1" 
permanent="true" processing="stop"/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<rewrite url="^~/Product/id/([^/\\\'=]+)/?$" to="~/View/Product.aspx?id=$1" permanent="true" processing="stop"/>
<rewrite url="^~/Product/id/([^\\\'=]+)/$" to="~/View/Product.aspx?id=$1" permanent="true" processing="stop"/>
<rewrite url="^~/Product/id/([^\\\'=]+)$" to="~/View/Product.aspx?id=$1" permanent="true" processing="stop"/>
```

Please try to add this configuration to handle the error.

- The first line is your original code.
- The second will handle slash inside the product id and also at the end of the URL.
- The last will handle slash inside the product id and without slash at the end of the URL.

Comment: Your a life saver. This worked perfectly and handles all possible combinations that may occur. plus explanation. :)